# How to make muliple <ul> tag inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three `<ul>` tag, I want them to display inline or all at same line. Currently they were displayed as block and looks separated.

Instead of displaying :

```
All

Apple Banana Strawberry

Red Green White Blue Purple Blue
```

I want them to display as:

```
 All Apple Banana Strawberry Red Green White Blue Purple Blue
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.filters {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

ul.filters>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.filters>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #434e5e;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

ul.filters>li>a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

ul.filters>li.active>a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="all" data-filter-group="all">
      <li class="active" data-filter="*"><a href="#!">All</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="type" data-filter-group="type">
      <li data-filter=".harcos"><a href="#!">Apple</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".technika"><a href="#!">Banana</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".dramatic"><a href="#!">Strawberry</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="color" data-filter-group="color">
      <li data-filter=".red"><a href="#!">red</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".green"><a href="#!">green</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".white"><a href="#!">white</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".purple"><a href="#!">purple</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".blue"><a href="#!">blue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IF you use bootstrap just insert your ul into 2 divs like this  <div class="col-sm-6"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the display property of `ul.filters`. See below the working fiddle.

Note- Due to lack of space purple and blue are showing in the next line.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.filters {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

ul.filters>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

ul.filters>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #434e5e;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

ul.filters>li>a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

ul.filters>li.active>a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="all" data-filter-group="all">
      <li class="active" data-filter="*"><a href="#!">All</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="type" data-filter-group="type">
      <li data-filter=".harcos"><a href="#!">Apple</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".technika"><a href="#!">Banana</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".dramatic"><a href="#!">Strawberry</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="color" data-filter-group="color">
      <li data-filter=".red"><a href="#!">red</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".green"><a href="#!">green</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".white"><a href="#!">white</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".purple"><a href="#!">purple</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".blue"><a href="#!">blue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, why is Apple(actual text) is not clickable?

Comment: It was due to overlapping. I have fixed it with a margin. Please check again

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using bootstrap, so a better approach is to wrap the `<ul>` elements into **bootstrap columns(grid)**, that way you can also control the width and alignment of these `<ul>` elements on various screen sizes, alternatively you can also give the column classes to directly `<ul>` elements.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.filters {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

ul.filters>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.filters>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #434e5e;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

ul.filters>li>a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

ul.filters>li.active>a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-6">
    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="all" data-filter-group="all">
      <li class="active" data-filter="*"><a href="#!">All</a></li>

    </ul>
   </div><!-- ./col -->
   <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-6">
    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="type" data-filter-group="type">
      <li data-filter=".harcos"><a href="#!">Apple</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".technika"><a href="#!">Banana</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".dramatic"><a href="#!">Strawberry</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!-- ./col -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-6">
    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="color" data-filter-group="color">
      <li data-filter=".red"><a href="#!">red</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".green"><a href="#!">green</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".white"><a href="#!">white</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".purple"><a href="#!">purple</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".blue"><a href="#!">blue</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!-- ./col -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `<ul>` items `display: inline-block` and remove the `width: 100%` property.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


ul.filters {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

ul.filters>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.filters>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #434e5e;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

ul.filters>li>a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

ul.filters>li.active>a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="all" data-filter-group="all">
      <li class="active" data-filter="*"><a href="#!">All</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="type" data-filter-group="type">
      <li data-filter=".harcos"><a href="#!">Apple</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".technika"><a href="#!">Banana</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".dramatic"><a href="#!">Strawberry</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="color" data-filter-group="color">
      <li data-filter=".red"><a href="#!">red</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".green"><a href="#!">green</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".white"><a href="#!">white</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".purple"><a href="#!">purple</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".blue"><a href="#!">blue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's correct, but he use bootstrap maybe he can just insert the ul into 2 divs with bootstrap class :)

Comment: I didn't notice that, that's fair. @Sfili_81

Answer (score 1):

You should change your ul.filters to

```
ul.filters { display: inline-block; ...}
```

and it can solve the problem I think. Good Luck.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.filters {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

ul.filters>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.filters>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #434e5e;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

ul.filters>li>a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

ul.filters>li.active>a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-inline-flex">

    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center " data-group="all" data-filter-group="all">
      <li class="active" data-filter="*"><a href="#!">All</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="type" data-filter-group="type">
      <li data-filter=".harcos"><a href="#!">Apple</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".technika"><a href="#!">Banana</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".dramatic"><a href="#!">Strawberry</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="col col-4 option-set filters filter-group text-center" data-group="color" data-filter-group="color">
      <li data-filter=".red"><a href="#!">red</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".green"><a href="#!">green</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".white"><a href="#!">white</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".purple"><a href="#!">purple</a></li>
      <li data-filter=".blue"><a href="#!">blue</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```